# How to get the list of ELB and the details from AWS accounts accross all regions

Tags: php, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

Is there a way I could get all the elb and its details across  all regions in aws account. Is there any api available on aws or any tools that i can use to fetch data. thanks in advance

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/cli/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) There is a feature called `resource groups`

> Resource Groups and a Tag Editor. Resource Groups allow you to easily create, maintain, and view a collection of resources that share common tags. The new Tag Editor allows you to easily manage tags **across services and Regions**. You can search globally and edit tags in bulk, all with a couple of clicks.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/resource-groups-and-tagging/

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsconsolehelpdocs/latest/gsg/what-are-resource-groups.html

2) run with aws cli command or [AWS SDK for PHP](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/) as you tagged.